# What to place underneath a convection microwave oven?

Tags: oven

I bought a Sharp convection microwave oven months ago but to date, I have only used its microwave functions. The reason is because I am worried about the heat generated by the oven in the convection mode and what it might do to the wood-based countertop. What can I place on the countertop to protect it from the heat of the oven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your oven is not broken, you probably shouldn't need to place anything underneath it. I just reviewed few instruction manuals of Sharp convection microwave ovens and found no word about it. There was a warning about putting things on top of their ovens, but nothing about things under them in "safety" section.

That said:

1. Read your instruction manual, especially "SAFETY INSTRUCTIONS" section.
2. If you still don't trust it, you can try using a wooden cutting board. If nothing happens with it, probably nothing will happen to your countertop, either.
3. Stone or metal pad might help to diffuse heat, but also may get slippery easier than wood can. You don't want your oven to fall on the floor, so please be careful not to turn it into "medicine worse than the disease" situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd get a small granite or marble "cutting" board just the size of the oven.

It will help diffuse the heat.

Answer (score 2):

I have two, both Panasonic. One is on solid oak, the other on solid beech (the latter in my camper van). There's never been a smell of hot wood (or hot worktop oil) and no scorch marks, including after long use in oven mode. They are designed to be safe on typical work surfaces and have some space underneath and insulating feet.

Comment: I have the means to measure the temperature of the underside and the worktop after use, but may not have the time any time soon